# Rubymine rake task debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rake, rubymine

I'm trying to debug rake task in rubymine. I created debug configuration for this task. Ruby SDK I chose project SDK. When I try to run this I got:

```
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.1.1. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.

/home/arkency/RubyProject/trainer/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'

/home/arkency/RubyProject/trainer/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

/home/arkency/RubyProject/trainer/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'

/home/tomek/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:86:in `debug_load'

/home/tomek/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:86:in `debug_program'

/home/tomek/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/bin/rdebug-ide:110:in `<top (required)>'
```

When I run task from terminal all works fine. I don't know from where rubymine takes this rake gem. How to check it? How to change to use the proper Gem? Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click Run => Debug => Edit Configurations, select Bundler tab and check the `Run the script in context of the bundle`